# Exception Handling with Enterprise Library 5.0

Tags: c#, wcf, enterprise-library

First I will explain the structure of my project:

I have a WCF-service

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private QueryHandler _queryHandler;

    public MyService()
    {
        _queryHandler = new QueryHandler();
    }

    public MyObject GetMyObject(string param1, string param2)
    {
        return _queryHandler.GetMyObject(param1, param2);
    }
}
```

The QueryHandler-class is in a different project, and is the place where I query my database.

I'm a bit confused which approach to take regarding the Exception Handling Application Block:
Do I put a try...catch around every dataaccess code in the queryhandler and do the exception handling like:

```
try
{
    //Do something
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ExceptionManager exManager = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<ExceptionManager>();
    Exception exceptionToThrow;
    bool rethrow = exManager.HandleException(ex, "Exceptions Policy", out exceptionToThrow);

    if (rethrow)
    {
        if (exceptionToThrow == null)
        {
            throw;
        }
        else
        {
            throw exceptionToThrow;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

or do I put it in my webservice-class like:

```
    public MyObject GetMyObject(string param1, string param2)
    {
        var exceptionManager = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<ExceptionManager>();
        return exceptionManager.Process(() => _queryHandler.GetMyObject(param1, param2), "Exceptions Policy"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned WCF, you can use the built in [`[ExceptionShielding]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664738%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx) attribute to handle your exceptions in your service.

You will end up with something like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
  [OperationContract]
  [FaultContract(typeof(FaultContracts.GetMyObjectFault))]
  MyObject GetMyObject(string param1, string param2);
}

[ExceptionShielding("GetMyObjectServicePolicy")]
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private QueryHandler _queryHandler;

    public MyService()
    {
        _queryHandler = new QueryHandler();
    }

    public MyObject GetMyObject(string param1, string param2)
    {
        return _queryHandler.GetMyObject(param1, param2);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be my next step ;-) But if I understand correctly, when using ExceptionShielding, I don't need to use any try...catch anymore? Or do I still have to put them in my QueryHandler-class?

Comment: When using the attribute you wouldn't need to worry about any `try{}catch{}` blocks in your code as the shielding policy should take care of that for you.  You might still need `try{}catch{}` blocks in `QueryHandler` if you can recover from an exception, but if all the policy does is `rethrow` I would leave the handling to the shielding attribute.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Still need to do some reading about the shielding, but this is a great help.